# Rails form_for syntax in parent child association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to wrap my head around the form_for syntax, when using parent/child associations. Basically my question is, what are the differences in the following, as I've seen most of them being used:

```
<%= form_for (Child.parent) do |f| %>

<%= form_for (@child.parent) do |f| %>

<%= form_for (@child, @parent) do |f| %>

<%= form_for (@child, @parent.child) do |f| %>

<%= form_for (Child, @parent) do |f| %>

<%= form_for ([Child.parent]) do |f| %>

<%= form_for ([@parent.child]) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on what you're trying to accomplish. I've used this before:

`<%= form_for [@parent, @child] do |f| %>`

or even with a namespace:

`<%= form_for [:namespace, @child] do |f| %>`

If you're looking for nested fields perhaps this would be more what you're looking for:

```
<%= form_for @parent do |f| %>

    ...

    <%= f.fields_for :children do |builder| %> 
        <%= render "child_fields", f: builder %>
    <% end %>

    ...

<% end %>
```